# Python: override a helper function call in a base class

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding

is this possible to do in python?

module A:

```
def _helper:
    print('helper_a')

class A():
    def foo(self):
        _helper()
```

module B:

```
def _helper:
    print('helper_b')

class B(A):
    """ Somehow make B.foo call module B _helper without overriding A.foo"""
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you call `B().foo()`?  You might look into name mangling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_helper` is just a global in module A. You can set it to something else, and then the call to `A().foo()` will use that new global. This is called *monkey patching*.

However, if you want to patch `_helper` *only when you use `class B`*, then you'd have to patch and un-patch each and every time. This can be done but is not thread-safe, and generally should only be used if you can't refactor module A to begin with:

```
class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        orig_helper = moduleA._helper
        moduleA._helper = _helper
        try:
            return super().foo()
        finally:
            moduleA._helper = orig_helper
```

You may as well just override `foo` on class `B`:

```
def _helper:
    print('helper_b')

class B(A):
    """ Somehow make B.foo call module B _helper without overriding A.foo"""
    def foo(self):
        _helper()
```

If you can refactor module A, you could make the `_helper` function a static function on the class:

```
class A():
    @staticmethod
    def _helper():
        print('helper_a')

    def foo(self):
        self._helper()
```

at which point you can supply an alternative version on `B`:

```
class B():
    @staticmethod
    def _helper():
        print('helper_b')
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, that is exacly the information I was looking for and extremely helpful.